# Ionic 2 upgrade: Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to upgrade my Ionic environment to the latest version.

I currently have:

```
Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

**Question**

How do I get the following upgraded:

```
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
```

I have tried:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Which updated this to the latest:

```
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
```

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Here is my `package.json`.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.4.0",
    "accounts-base-client-side": "^0.1.1",
    "accounts-phone": "0.0.1",
    "angular2-meteor": "^0.6.2",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "^0.1.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^0.8.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "^1.3.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jose-jwe-jws": "git+https://github.com/square/js-jose.git",
    "meteor-client-side": "^1.3.4",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.8",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-tslint": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash.camelcase": "^4.3.0",
    "lodash.upperfirst": "^4.3.1",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "tslint-ionic-rules": "^0.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "name": "theWhoZoo",
  "description": "theWhoZoo: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    {
      "variables": {
        "SENDER_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "locator": "phonegap-plugin-push",
      "id": "phonegap-plugin-push"
    }
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `npm install` ? You can change  row at change your package.json file and try `npm install`